# My Vue build in webpack produces a huge (850kb) vendor file, how do I make it the expected 85kb?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, vue.js

**Solved:**

```
devtool: '#eval-source-map'
```

Includes a source map in the output

**Original issue**

As stated, the webpack build produces an enormous bundle/vendor file with Vue as my only import. I cannot see for the life of me how people get it down to 80kb.

As far as I can see, there is a vue-loader and the file gets minified, so why would it come out enormous?

```
var path = require('path') var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {   entry: './src/main.js',   output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
    publicPath: '/static/',
    filename: 'js/login-view.js'   },   module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]',
          useRelativePath: true,
          publicPath: './static/images/'
        }
      }
    ]   },   resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']   },   devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true   },   performance: {
    hints: false   },   devtool: '#eval-source-map' }

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {   // module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'   // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html   module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: false,
      // compress: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      mangle: true,
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })   ]) }
```

Comment: When you generate the bundle you specify production?

Comment: Yes, but the sourcemap was always getting pulled into Dev and prod. I wrapped it in a check (if Dev) to get rid of the bloat.

Answer (score 1):

```
devtool: '#eval-source-map'
```

was the culprit. It was getting included in all builds and it puts the sourcemap in the files. I removed this and dropped the file to ~90kb.